# When copying files using Apps Script from one folder to another any "Apps Script" files being copied end up in MyDrive not the specified folder - why?

Tags: google-apps-script, file-copying

I use this Apps Script to make backup copies of some files:

```
var sourceFolderId = "xxxxxx";
var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
var latestFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
var backupFolderId = "yyyyyy";
var backupFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(backupFolderId);

while(latestFiles.hasNext()) {
 var file = latestFiles.next();
 file.makeCopy(backupFolder);
}
```

It works fine - copying all files from the source folder to the backup folder-  except that if any file being copied is a "Google Apps script" file it doesn't copy it to the backup folder, it copies it to "My Drive".

I then have to move it from "My Drive" to the required folder.  I can do this with a script but I can't work out why it is doing this in the first place.

I am the owner of all the files and folders.

Any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also in my environment, I confirmed the same situation with you. Only Google Apps Scripts cannot be copied to the backup folder. I think that this may be a bug. So I thought of the workaround for this situation. The patterns I tested are as follows.

1. Tried to move the copied GAS files from "My Drive" to the backup folder using `addFile()` and `removeFile()`.

   - A parent ID of backup folder can be added. But the parent ID of "My Drive" cannot be removed.

     - Failure
2. Tried to copy GAS files using `Drive.Files.copy` of Advanced Google Services.

   - The copied GAS files are created to "My Drive". This is the same to `makeCopy()`.

     - Failure
3. Tried to move the copied GAS files from "My Drive" to the backup folder using `Drive.Files.update` of Advanced Google Services.

   - The parent ID can be changed from "My Drive" to backup folder.

     - **Success**

### Modified script :

In this modified script, Google Apps Script files are moved from "My Drive" to backup folder using `Drive.Files.update`.

```
var sourceFolderId = "xxxxxx";
var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
var latestFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
var backupFolderId = "yyyyyy";
var backupFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(backupFolderId);

while(latestFiles.hasNext()) {
  var file = latestFiles.next();
  var res = file.makeCopy(backupFolder); // Modified
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) { // Added
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": backupFolderId}]}, res.getId()); // Added
  }
}
```

### Note :

In order to use this modified script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services and API console as follows.

#### Enable Drive API v2 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Drive API v2

#### [Enable Drive API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com/)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Drive". And click Drive API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

#### References :

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi.  That's a nice workaround.  I was using iterating through all MyDrive files and using .addFile and .removeFile  but your's is neater.  I'm glad it's not just me - presumably then it is a bug.

Comment: @MrPea I could know about this situation like a bug from your question. Thank you.

Comment: Have you got any suggestions for using this update method for creating a google docs files in a team drive folder?  I've tried it in API explorer but I don't understand how to implement the syntax in google apps script.